# Facebook Graph API not showing shares

Tags: wordpress, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I need help with Facebook counts on Shareaholic wordpress plugin?
There is a post I know that should be showing shares/likes on the share bar, but nothing is showing. When I look at the URL in Facebook Debugger, I can see the URL is getting an oAuth error, although I have no idea how to fix it. I have the Facebook OGP plugin and have linked my Facebook app and most URLs work ok, but this particular one is not.

If I go here: http://graph.facebook.com/http://www.amyjbennett.com/2015/10/06/feathers-season-2-episode-9-with-heather-tollison/

you'll see I get the ID but not the shares.

But, the graph API that I found in my Facebook Developer application for this URL returns:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "An access token is required to request this resource.",
            "type": "OAuthException",
            "code": 104,
            "fbtrace_id": "BIuSensfLPZ"
    }
}
```

How can I get it to return without error and include the shares (which I know it has).

Answer (score 1):

I think you should first get oAuth from Facebook graph login url then it will give you the access token(which is temporary generally) and  save it to your database or session and use that access token to get resources of graphAPI. The following link might help.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web